# Added column stays invisible after adding it to Listview

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

In WM_CREATE message of my main window procedure I create a listview with the next code:

```
hMyList = CreateWindowA( WC_LISTVIEW,TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
          LVS_LIST | LVS_TYPEMASK , XPOS(450), YPOS(20), NWIDTH(200),   
          NHEIGHT(200),hWnd,(HMENU) 9876, hInst, NULL);
```

Then I insert code to add a column to that listview:

```
LVCOLUMN column;    
column.mask = LVCF_TEXT; 
column.pszText = "Name";
SendMessage(hMyList, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, NULL, (LPARAM)&column );
//returns 0; so everything is fine
```

But column doesn't appear in the listview.
What can be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns are visible only in report/details view of the listview. To switch it in that mode you should post LVM_SETVIEW message to it, or use LVS_REPORT style instead of LVS_LIST in the CreateWindowA.